# Convert data of rabbit mq queue in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I'm building a microservice that receives data from another microservice and i'm having trouble while converting the data. I'm a beginner at rabbit MQ and don't know how to fix it.

[image: Error]

That it is my class to convert the message

```
@Configuration
public class MensagemConfig {

    @Value("${crud.rabbitmq.exchange}")
    String exchange;

    @Bean
    public Exchange exchange() {
        return ExchangeBuilder.directExchange(exchange).durable(true).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

And here is my consumer class:

```
@Component
public class CasoConsumer {
    
    @Autowired
    private CasoLVRepository repository;

    public CasoConsumer(CasoLVRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "crud.statistics.caso")
    public void consumer(@Payload CasoLV caso){
        repository.save(caso);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show the code of the producer

Answer (score 0):

You should also register the converter

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;


    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter) {
        final var rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(converter);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }
```

And, if your consumer consumes the json objects, the producer must also product json messages